How to push 10-ft long 4" PVC pipe into 90-deg Elbow Hub?
I'm connecting 10ft 4" PVC to the outlet of a 26' long channel drain that runs across our garage. The PVC pipe connects to the outlet at 90-deg angle.
The trench for the PVC wasn't dug at a perfect 90-deg angle so the 10ft PVC pipe doesn't fit into the 90-deg elbow very well. We're trying our best to shape the trench so that the PVC pipe connects close to 90-deg. Because the pipe is so long, it's hard to grip and push into the elbow.
Nothing is glued yet (the adapter is glued to the endcap of the drain, but this assembly isn't glued into the channel drain yet).
I was thinking of gluing in the following order:

The wye (maintenance) connector to the 10ft PVC
A short 12"L section of 4" PVC to the Wye
A 90-deg elbow into the 12"L PVC
The 23"L 4" PVC into the other leg of the 90-deg elbow
The endcap/adapter into the channel drain (to give me a chance to run GS121 water sealant).
The whole assembly in step 4 to the adapter of step 5.

Is there a better way to do this?




assemble it on the driveway, then slide it into position

What about an 11.25 degree elbow

While each 10 foot stick seems fairly rigid, you'd be surprised how much the assembled 20 ft will bend (without any heat applied) to fit the curve in that trench.

The channel drain must be in precisely the right place to serve its function and achieve an acceptable appearance. So anchor that part in place first and build the drainage from there.
After securing the channel drain in place I'd re-measure to assure that 23" is the correct length, accounting for slip into the fittings, and then cement that into either side of the elbow. Next cement the 12" pipe into the inlet side of the wye.
With those two sub-assemblies built, cement the free end of the 23" into the channel drain and then quickly cement the free end of the 12" into the elbow. I'd do it in this sequence because this improves my odds of getting the elbow rotated at the correct angle (neither upward, nor downward too steep) and of getting the cleanout on the wye oriented nicely upward.
Now.. about that off-angle (and curvy, too?) trench problem.
One way to achieve a small bend is to use couplings: each solvent-weld joint allows a few degrees of deflection away from perfectly straight. Multiple couplings in close succession could allow you to accumulate several degrees of bend. As this is a non-pressurized drainage application, a rubber "Fernco" type coupling would be appropriate too. It's easy to get several degrees of bend by inserting pipes crooked in one of those.
Another way to achieve some bend is to bend the pipe. PVC pipe bends readily when heated. Use a propane torch or high-temperature hot air gun and "brush" the pipe over a distance of a foot or two. Try to heat the full circumference of the pipe evenly -- easier said than done with a pipe of this size. Gradually the pipe will become soft and bendable.
If you're in the mood to experiment try putting a section of pipe into an oven of some sort (perhaps the BBQ grill?). Use low heat; the pipe only needs to reach around 210-275 °F to soften.
You could use the couplings or the bend technique in the 23" section or in the 10 foot sections, or both. A bit of bend in the 23" section might be enough to allow the 10 foot section to remain unbent.

Boiling water poured over it works for bending PVC pipe if you are careful to bend, not kink it.

Had ready-mix concrete poured last Friday. Took 30 minutes to pour 1.5 cuyd ($650), vibrated concrete while pouring, then ~3 hours to trowel/distribute/mag-float. Waited 4 hours for the concrete to partially set, then I had to come back with 50 lb of vinyl concrete patch to build a ramp over the risen channel drain (more on this below).
One thing the dumb NDS Channel Drain install video didn't tell me was that the channel drain might LIFT during the concrete pour if you vibrate the concrete. I staked/buried my rebar at least 3-4" down but the concrete vibrator + buoyancy lifted the channel drain 1/4-3/8" above ground-level. This was almost catastrophic, had I not quickly placed some weights on the drain:



There was a 1/8 - 1/4" lip from the channel drain along 80% of the length of the drain after the concrete had dried. I had to lay down vinyl concrete patch over it so cars won't damage it.




And now I have a different problem.

Thanks Greg, for the awesome advice. I followed your suggestion for gluing up the PVC.
The channel drain was made out of HDPE (High Density Polyethylene) and required a special 3M "8005" glue to glue on the end cap.
I also fixed the spalted concrete underneath the garage doors using 20 lb of vinyl concrete patch.
I tried using a propane hand (pipe welder) torch and a stick-style 20-gal propane torch but was barely able to bend the PVC. The outer PVC skin started to yellow and smoke (we took care not to inhale the fumes), but the PVC was not pliable. I might have applied too much heat too fast onto the surface while the inner portion of the pipe wasn't heated. If I were to do this again, I'd try smaller heat for a longer period of time.
I buried the PVC first with small rocks that we'd dug up for drainage (in case a section broke/leakage), then refilled.
Called a ready-mix company for 1.5 cuyd of concrete delivery next week. $600, not bad!
Anyway, this is how it turned out:




